# Can Endermen teleport while carrying a block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I occasionally have Endermen teleport into my mines, creating the possibility that they may move a block of dirt or gravel and inadvertently open up holes for monsters to spill through, ruining the relative safety of my dig sites. As such, I have taken to sealing my mine walls by removing dirt and gravel and replacing it with spare cobblestone.

Unfortunately, I happened to notice an Enderman in what I *thought* was a dirt-and-gravel-free mine branch wandering around with a block of dirt. Either I failed to replace some dirt (which he subsequently moved) or he picked it up somewhere else and teleported in with it.

Is the second explanation possible? Can Endermen teleport while carrying a block?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Yes

1. **Spawn Endermen**

   [image]
2. **Wait for one to pick up a block**

   [image]
3. **Hit Enderman**
4. **Observe teleportation**

   [image]

Comment: Ahhh, you can't beat a sound experiment!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they can.

Endermen don't drop any carried items when they teleport.

They also can't spawn with blocks, so if you see an Enderman with a dirt block, you're guaranteed to find a missing dirt block *somewhere* nearby.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my world an enderman picked up a grass block from a structure that I liked so I tried to kill it to make it drop it's block but it teleported and I saw it behind me holding it's block.

Comment: Hey Planner, and welcome to Arqade. Just a couple of things: if you see an existing answer that you think is good, just leave an upvote instead of a new answer.  Also, if you have a new question, go ahead an [ask it](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!  I realize you can't upvote just yet, but it doesn't take long to get that privilege.